# how to detect static function in Clang AST C++

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

How to detect whether the function is static or not while walking through FunctionDecl in Clang ASt C++. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

'FunctionDecl::getStorageClass()' is available to get storage class specifier written on the declaration,
or 'NamedDecl::getFormalLinkage()' to get actual linkage for the symbol declared.

For example:

```
             /* getStorageClass() , getFormalLinkage() */
       void func0(); /* SC_None   , ExternalLinkage */
static void func1(); /* SC_Static , InternalLinkage */
extern void func2(); /* SC_Extern , ExternalLinkage */

static void func3(); /* SC_Static , InternalLinkage */
       void func3(); /* SC_None   , InternalLinkage */
extern void func3(); /* SC_Extern , InternalLinkage */

class C
{
  static void func4(); /* SC_Static , ExternalLinkage */
};
```